# What is the runtime of the following code

Tags: algorithm, code-analysis

The code is as follows:

```
Ans = 1;
while( N > 0)
{
     Ans = Ans*2;
     N = N/2;
 }
```

I can not figure out how N = N/2 will effect the runtime. I tried to find a pattern by checking how many times the loop would run if N = 1 .. 7 but I didnt notice any pattern. I think I must be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Seriously? N → N/2, N/2 → (N/2)/2 = N/4 ... and you don't see a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the asymptotic notation, the Big-Oh, the complexity will be `O(logn)`. Count the operations and you will see that they are in fact a logarithm of base two.

The asymptotic notation basically tells you that the algorithm doesn't run **slower** than the given function of complexity. Most of the calculations can be seen from the code right away, however in the more complex algorithms, a calculation of instructions is needed.

Comment: No problem, could you accept one of the answers provided if your question has been answered in order to resolve the issue?

Comment: oh whoops, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive equation for your code:

```
T(n)=T(n/2)+O(1)
Time complexity is O(logn)
```